# How to get the current *ngFor value on Button click?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, ngfor

I've been trying to get the data.login of the data item on which user has clicked the avatar image. The HTML code is below.
I tried everything i could on the web but couldn't make it work.
How to get the current data.login to the corresponding .TS file.

Code:

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of uarr" class="list-unstyled" >
    <li>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <a routerLink="/" >
                <img class="github-avatar" src="{{data.avatar_url}}" >
              </a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="text-center">{{ data.login }}</h3>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    </li>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Click Event

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of uarr" class="list-unstyled"  >
    <li>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail" (click)="onClick(data.login)">
              <a routerLink="/" >
                <img class="github-avatar" src="{{data.avatar_url}}" >
              </a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="text-center">{{ data.login }}</h3>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    </li>
```

**TS**

```
onClick(login){
console.log(login);
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Exactly what I was looking for.